# Gstreamer pipeline, videorate not working as intended

Tags: gstreamer

I'm using Gstreamer to take 4 videos (MKV container, Mjpeg codec, 25 frames per second, 5 minutes long) to generate a "wall" of videos (basically a 2x2 matrix). I'm using the following pipeline:

```
#!/bin/sh
gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace !  jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=$1.avi \
uridecodebin uri="file://${PWD}/$1/1.mkv" ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=300,height=200, framerate=25/1 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
uridecodebin uri="file://${PWD}/$1/2.mkv" ! videoscale  ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=300,height=200,framerate=25/1 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-300 ! mix. \
uridecodebin uri="file://${PWD}/$1/3.mkv" ! videoscale  ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=300,height=200,framerate=25/1 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-200 left=0 ! mix. \
uridecodebin uri="file://${PWD}/$1/4.mkv" ! videoscale  ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=300,height=200,framerate=25/1 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-200 left=-300 ! mix. \
```

The code works, but the end result is only 17 seconds long instead of 5 minutes like the source videos and it doesn't seem like I'm using the videorate element properly -- the output video seems to randomly "speed up", reading frames as they become available instead of maintaining the speed of the original videos.

Interestingly enough, when the source files are .wmv (Windows Media 9 codec) everything appears to be working just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your capsfilter in quotes ... videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=300,height=200, framerate=25/1" ! videobox ...
Also try videomixer2